# Error de sintaxis en SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

Intenté actualizar elementos de una tabla con el siguiente código SQL

```
WITH tmp(prop_name, property) AS (VALUES ('Brand', 'Example'))
    UPDATE Property 
    SET
        prop_name = tmp.prop_name, property = tmp.property
    FROM tmp 
    WHERE Property.name == tmp.name;
```

me muestra el siguiente error de sintaxis:

> near "FROM": syntax error

Dado que soy bastante novato utilizando SQL, no he podido hallar el error. Lo que si tengo entendido es que podría estar sobre from.

pd: Estoy utilizando este metodo para actualizar múltiples elementos de una tabla en una sola operación de forma dinámica, esto es debido a que estoy haciendo un sistema que requiere de esa funcionalidad en python y no estoy seguro de si sqlalchemy tiene una función que lo haga. También lo hago para saber si se puede, si no, aceptare cualquier solución alternativa.

Comment: Estoy oxídado en sql, pero el `FROM` es necesario en un update? No es suficiente sólo con el nombre de la tabla al lado? Además, creo que quieres hacer una especie de UPDATE y JOIN. En ese caso, investiga sobre "correlated subqueries"

Comment: @Cuauhtli Ok gracias, voy a investigar sobre eso. El código de la pregunta lo hice basandome en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11564251/14975176)

Comment: @Cuauhtli Investigué sobre las correlated subqueries y si, tienes razón. Removí el from y utilice las correlated subqueries para asignar nuevos valores y todo funcionó adecuadamente. Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Podrías responder tu propia pregunta con la solución que encontraste? Puedes crear una respuesta y marcar tu propia respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta es, en primer lugar, remover el FROM porque ahí no se está haciendo nada, no es necesario y por eso lanza el error de sintaxis. Y dentro de las asignaciones del SET, no hay que poner tmp porque no se invocó desde el FROM, por decirlo de alguna manera.
La solución sería utilizar "correlated subqueries", como indicó @Cuauhtli en su comentario. El código correcto sería el siguiente:

```
WITH tmp(id, prop_name, property) AS (VALUES (12345, 'Brand', 'Example'))
UPDATE Property
SET
    prop_name = (SELECT prop_name
            FROM tmp
            WHERE Property.id == tmp.id)

    property = (SELECT property
            FROM tmp
            WHERE Property.id == tmp.id)

WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp)
```

A prop_name, property se le asignan los valores que están dentro de tmp con una "correlated subqueries" donde (WHERE) se comprueban las id de tmp y las id de la tabla Property. Si se cumple, se extrae el valor seleccionado(SELECT) desde(FROM) tmp.

El código de la última linea selecciona todas las tablas que tengan el id de tmp.
Así lo entiendo con mi escaso conocimiento de SQL